# Android: mp3 does not play

Tags: android, mp3, android-mediaplayer

I get no sound when trying to play my mp3. Do I need to enable something in the manifest?
I found some example that just created the mediaplayer and called start.

I only call prepare after stop has been called.

The log shows 2 start messages and 2 stop messages every time I push the play button. Why 2?

The code:

```
package com.xx.yy;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainMenuFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener
{
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private boolean pressed = false;
    private boolean stopped = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {               
        View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.main_menu_layout, container, false );

        view.setBackgroundResource( 0 );

        Button play = (Button) view.findViewById( R.id.play_button );
        play.setOnClickListener( this );

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create( getActivity(), R.raw.qa2pir_projektrespekt );

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick( View view ) 
    {
        if ( !pressed )
        {
            try 
            {
                if ( stopped )
                {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();
                pressed = true;
            } 
            catch ( IllegalStateException e ) 
            {
                Log.d( "IllegalState", e.toString() );
            } 
            catch ( IOException e ) 
            {
                Log.d( "IO", e.toString() );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            pressed = false;
            stopped = true;
        }
    }

}
```

The layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" 
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/play"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

The manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xx.yy"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.sj.replicator.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 MediaPlayer mPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), com.cea_new.R.raw.c2hindi);;
    mPlayer.start();
```

Try this code.'com.cea_new' is my package name so replace it with your package name.

Here the R.raw.filename is not working because its is a fragment in activity only R.raw.filename will work